# Android: Realm not creating all tables on initial run

Tags: android, realm

I cannot figure out why Realm is not creating all tables on initial run of my android application. When the app runs, only 2 of the 6 tables are created. I have followed documentation, that all model classes must extend the RealmObject class. I am using the latest version of Realm (5.7.0).

[image]

Here is one of my classes that are not added to the realm schema:

```
public class Category extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("categoryID")
private int categoryID;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("dateAdded")
private String dateAdded;
@SerializedName("isDeleted")
private int isDeleted;

public Category(int categoryID, String name, String dateAdded, int isDeleted) {
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
    this.name = name;
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}
public Category() { }

protected Category(Parcel in) {
    categoryID = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    dateAdded = in.readString();
    isDeleted = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(categoryID);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(dateAdded);
    dest.writeInt(isDeleted);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<Category> CREATOR = new Creator<Category>() {
    @Override
    public Category createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Category(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Category[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Category[size];
    }
};

public int getCategoryID() {
    return categoryID;
}

public void setCategoryID(int categoryID) {
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}

public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}

public int getIsDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setIsDeleted(int isDeleted) {
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}
```

}

Here is a class that realm does add to the schema:

```
public class ClientInfo extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("clientInfoID")
private int clientInfoID;
@SerializedName("platform")
private String platform;
@SerializedName("dateAdded")
private String dateAdded;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;
@SerializedName("codeName")
private String codeName;
@SerializedName("versionNumber")
private double versionNumber;
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;
@SerializedName("isDeleted")
private int isDeleted;

public ClientInfo() {

}

protected ClientInfo(Parcel in) {
    clientInfoID = in.readInt();
    platform = in.readString();
    dateAdded = in.readString();
    description = in.readString();
    codeName = in.readString();
    versionNumber = in.readDouble();
    status = in.readString();
    isDeleted = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<ClientInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<ClientInfo>() {
    @Override
    public ClientInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ClientInfo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ClientInfo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ClientInfo[size];
    }
};

public int getClientInfoID() {
    return clientInfoID;
}

public void setClientInfoID(int clientInfoID) {
    this.clientInfoID = clientInfoID;
}

public String getPlatform() {
    return platform;
}

public void setPlatform(String platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
}

public String getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}

public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getCodeName() {
    return codeName;
}

public void setCodeName(String codeName) {
    this.codeName = codeName;
}

public double getVersionNumber() {
    return versionNumber;
}

public void setVersionNumber(double versionNumber) {
    this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public int getIsDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setIsDeleted(int isDeleted) {
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(clientInfoID);
    dest.writeString(platform);
    dest.writeString(dateAdded);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(codeName);
    dest.writeDouble(versionNumber);
    dest.writeString(status);
    dest.writeInt(isDeleted);
}
```

}

I use a JobIntentService to fetch data from my Web API... all calls to the API are successful, and realm does not throw an exception when write transactions are called. I have tried running a migration and that did not seem to work. What could be the issue with classes not being picked up by realm?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get data from the API for all your classes? Did you try to locally create a Category object and insert it?

Comment: Yes, my data comes from my web api. I did not try that - my thinking is, whether the API calls succeed or fail, the schema should have all my classes extending RealmObject which is not happening now.

Comment: To my experience, Realm adds classes only to its schema if you actually insert the first object of that class. Since it is not a relational database, it doesn't have actual tables. Simply try to insert a locally created Category object and see if Category is then in the schema.

Comment: Actually, Realm still has a schema, just not a relational schema. So it creates "tables" internally based on what it sees within the default RealmModule.

Comment: You have to find or insert operation from realm, if you see on Schema. Did you do this before looking Schema?